# Backslash '\' is causing error when passing over query string

Tags: c#, json.net, encode

I'm working on a solution to export a grid to excel on the server.

We are encoding the filters that go across the server via query string.

Here is that code that fails:

```
function encodeFilter(filter) {
    const operators = [">", "<", "=", "<>", ">=", "<=", "!"];
    let filterString = JSON.stringify(filter);
    return parseResult = JSON.parse(filterString, (key, val) => {
        if (typeof val === "string" && !operators.includes(val)) {
            if (val === null) {
                return val;
            }

            return encodeURIComponent(val);
        }
        return val;
    });
}
```

When we have a backslash in the field value as a filter it fails with this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path '[1]', line 1, position 30.
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)     
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
     at DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.Helpers.DataSourceLoadOptionsParser.Parse(DataSourceLoadOptionsBase loadOptions, Func`2 valueSource)
     at DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.DataSourceLoadOptionsHttpBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Here is an image with what is going across the server that is failing (kinda hard to see):

[image]

If I update the `encodeFilter` call and do not encode the `\`, it works perfect.

Why is encoding a backslash causing **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ".** error?

This code works perfect:

```
function encodeFilter(filter) {
    const operators = [">", "<", "=", "<>", ">=", "<=", "!"];
    let filterString = JSON.stringify(filter);
    return parseResult = JSON.parse(filterString, (key, val) => {
        if (typeof val === "string" && !operators.includes(val)) {
            if (val === null) {
                return val;
            }

            if (val === "\\") {
                return "\\"
            }

            return encodeURIComponent(val);
        }
        return val;
    });
}
```

Here is the JavaScript ajax call and Server call:

```
    const url = BuildSafeURL(`api/Grid/ExportGridData${paramValues.LoadOptionsParams}`, null);
    $.ajax(url, {
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(paramValues),
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == "") {
            hideLoadingPanelExcelServerExport();
            swal({
                type: 'info',
                title: 'No data to export',
                width: "auto"
            });
            return;
        }

        const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
        workbook.addWorksheet('Smart Grid Data');
        workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function () {
            hideLoadingPanelExcelServerExport();
            saveAs(new Blob([Base64ToBytes(data)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), exportFileName);
        });
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        **// THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS**
        console.log(jqXHR);
        swal({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Error exporting to Excel.',
            width: "auto"
        });
    })
    .always(function () {
        if (gridInstance) {
            prepareForExportOnServer(gridInstance, false).then(() => {
                gridInstance.endUpdate();
            })
        }

        hideLoadingPanelExcelServerExport();
    });

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExportGridData(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions, [FromBody] object paramValues)
        {
            // NEVER GETS TO THIS CALL
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean `if (val === "\\") {return "\\\\";}` ?

Comment: @Basic: I'm not sure what I mean? Does it need to be double escaped? I tried your code: `if (val === "\\") {  return "\\\\" }` and it doesn't work. It returns no data.

Comment: Well, if val="\\" return "\\" will change nothing, merely return the same "\" it started with. I was wondering if that was an attempt to escape the "\". Note that it's only "double escaped" because you're escaping once when you define the string in the editor/IDE. The compiler sees that block as "If val=\ return \" [Excuse the inconsistent quoting, it's hard to work around the escaping in the inline comment formatting]

Comment: @Basic: Yes, I guess it just is return \ and not escaping it -> it works when that occurs. I just can't figure out why when escaping it, it fails with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter:`

Comment: What does the raw JSON that you end up sending look like?  If you upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is it reported to be well-formed or malformed?